# How to use alphabets or roman numbers as index in Vuejs For loop?

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

Default iterator of for loop (v-for) in vuejs starts from 0,1,2,3...
How can we set the v-for to start index with i, ii, iii, or a, b,c instead of numbers.
for example this is the content:

```
let content = [
  "Content1",
  "Content2",
  "Content3",
  "Content4",
  "Content5",
  "Content6",
  "Content7",
  "Content8"
]
```

*the content array contains 100+ items for different products so i don't want
to manually add the roman numerals*

**I WANT THE OUTPUT TO LOOK LIKE THIS**

> i. Content1
>
> ii. Content2
>
> iii. Content3
>
> iv. Content4
>
> v. Content5
>
> vi. Content6
>
> vii. Content7
>
> viii. Content8

Comment: `v-for` enumerates arrays and objects. Arrays have their index starting at 0, and objects have whatever keys you put into them. So, simply make your objects using keys like i, ii, iii or a, b, c - and it will work.

Comment: @IVOGELOV i have already done that, i was looking for a built in function of vuejs.

Comment: Vue is a framework, not a library.  It doesn't try to provide library-style components for markup.  So the answer is no, there is no built-in function for roman numerals.

Comment: Create an array filled with the numerals and iterate it.  You can probably import a list or even a package like [roman-numerals](https://github.com/joshleaves/roman-numerals)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming content will be on data()

You can create a method:

```
toRoman(num, result = ''){
    const map = {
        M: 1000,
        CM: 900,
        D: 500,
        CD: 400,
        C: 100,
        XC: 90,
        L: 50,
        XL: 40,
        X: 10,
        IX: 9,
        V: 5,
        IV: 4,
        I: 1,
      };
      for (const key in map) {
        if (num >= map[key]) {
          if (num !== 0) {
            return this.toRoman(num - map[key], result + key);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
```

And access in the loop:

```
<div v-for="(cont, index) in content">
 {{toRoman(index).toLowerCase()}}. {{cont}}
</div>
```